# Product of $rx$ for $r\in m\backslash m^2$ and $x\in M\backslash mM$

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Suppose $(R,m)$ is a Noetherian local ring. $M\neq mM$ is an $R$-module( $M$ isn't assumed to be finitely generated). Let $r\in m\backslash m^2$ and $x\in M\backslash mM$, is it possible for $rx\in m^iM$ for some $i>1$ ?

This supposes to be easy, but I can't find any such examples

Comment: Can you prove this for $M$ finitely-generated?

Comment: @KentaS I believe I found such an example. Let $R=k[x_1,x_2]$, $M=k[x_1,x_2]/(x_1-x_2^2)$, $r=x_1$, $x=1$. Just consider localization then $1x_1=1x_2^2$ in $m^2M$.